# Ignore attributes inherited from parent context in Mustache templates

Tags: mustache

How do you ignore attributes inherited from parent context in Mustache templates? For example, consider this as template data:

```
{
  "name": "Alice",
  "age": 45,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": 11
    },
    {
      "name": "Clare"
    }
  ]
}
```

We can render the data using the following template:

```
<p>{{name}} (age {{age}})</p>
<ul>
  {{#children}}
    <li>{{name}} (age {{age}})</li>
  {{/children}}
</ul>
```

We will get the following HTML:

```
<p>Alice (age 45)</p>
<ul>
  <li>Bob (age 11)</li>
  <li>Clare (age 45)</li>
</ul>
```

How can you display the `age` attribute only when it is from the current context and not inherited from the parent context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to make sure there's a null value in the template data:

```
{
  "name": "Alice",
  "age": 45,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "age": 11
    },
    {
      "name": "Clare",
      "age": null
    }
  ]
}
```